# Capsule hotels in New-York JFK

Tags: layovers, hotels, jfk

I'll have a 5 hour layover in the JFK airport and I'll be suffering from jetlag. Is there a cheap capsule hotel where I can pay for, say, 3 hour stay and have a short nap?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you demonstrate your own attempts at research when asking; for example, what does the JFK website say? Please be sure to take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But asking this question I'd like to learn about real experience, pros & cons and opinions of "real" travellers. Such resources like airport site usually contain lots of marketing I'd like to avoid.

Comment: That doesn't absolve you of your responsibility to the community standards.

Comment: If you want opinions, try TripAdvisor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this [page](http://blog.sleepinginairports.net/2014/03/25/airport-sleeping-pods/) lists all the airports with sleeping pods inside the airport and JFK is not listed. Minute Suites indicates Chicago O'Hare is [coming](http://minutesuites.com/our-company/) but I can't find any company even planning to open a capsule hotel inside JFK much less having one right now. As the page above was last updated 15 December 2015 they are missing  JetBlue's [JetNap](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/jetblue-installs-napping-pods-for-customers-at-jfk-airport-300253447.html) which are indeed at JFK but they are only for twenty minutes which is close to useless and many reviews complain about questionable cleanliness.

If you want to go outside of the airport, obviously the question is too broad, it's practically impossible to even count the options to grab a quick shut eye around an airport the size of JFK.

Comment: A Yotel at JFK, that'd be a dream come true. I love Yotel. The article says "bidding" -- well, they didn't win the bid apparently.